# Problema con cola de servidor en sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

Tengo un servidor construido con sockets. Este servidor debe de atender a varios usuarios a la vez, en este caso solo 2, por lo que a cada nuevo usuario le asigne un nuevo hilo de trabajo donde básicamente se almacena la información del mensaje que le llega del cliente en una lista, y después de eso pongo a recorrer la lista para leer y responder cada uno de los mensajes que llega.

El problema es que los mensajes se enciman y no puedo responder a cada usuario como corresponde:

**Funcionamiento deseado**

```
lista = [
  [cliente1,"Hola como estas",socket],
  [cliente2,"Hola",socket].
  [cliente2,"que haces",socket]
]
cliente1: "Hola como estas"
-> "Bien Gracias"
cliente2: "Hola"
-> "Hola"
cliente2: "que haces"
-> "ok"
```

Lo que espero que haga es que los mensajes de los clientes se vayan apilando a medida que vayan llegando y después mostrar y responder de uno en uno los mensajes.

Pero el resultado que obtengo es similar a esto:

```
cliente1 : "Hola"
->"Hola" #Se repite el mensaje de cliente 1
"Hola" #Se repite el mensaje de cliente 1
cliente2 : "hola2"
->hola2
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionarlo dejo los códigos aqui abajo:

**Servidor.py**

```
import socket
import threading

mensajes = []


def RecibirConexion(cliente,direccion):
    print(threading.enumerate())
    while True:

        msg = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
        mensajes.append([cliente,msg,direccion])
        for mensaje in mensajes:
            print(mensaje[1])
            respuesta = input("> ")
            cliente.sendall(respuesta.encode())
            mensajes.remove(mensajes[mensaje])
    servidor.close()


servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = (socket.gethostname(),500)

servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(2)

lista1 = []


while True:
    cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

    threading.Thread(target=RecibirConexion,args=(cliente,direccion)).start()
```

**cliente.py**

```
import socket

conexion = ("Dell",500)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    linea = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(linea.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(respuesta)
cliente.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 problemas en tu aplicación: El manejo de la estructura de datos para la cola y la sincronización entre los hilos en el acceso a los datos compartidos.

Para la cola estás usando una lista y eliminando el elemento con `.remove()`, pero mira en este ejemplo lo que pasa al usar `.remove()` dentro de un `for`:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for x in l:
    print(x)
    if x == 3:
        l.remove(x)
# Imprime esto:
# 1
# 2
# 3 -> Después de eliminar el '3', debería continuar el for con el '4', no?...
# 5 -> ... pues no, porque ahora la siguiente posición está ocupada con el '5'
# 6
# 7
```

Debes usar el tipo de dato `queue` para esto y los métodos `.put()` y `.get()`. Esto sería la cola FIFO que necesitas

En cuanto al segundo problema piensa ¿Qué pasaría si mientras un cliente procesa sus mensajes (dentro del `for`) otro cliente envía un mensaje? Como `mensajes` es una lista global, el mensaje del cliente 2, entraria en la lista siendo procesado por el cliente 1 también. Incluso, lo podría procesar el cliente1 y borrarlo con `remove()` y luego el cliente 2 no lo encontraría. Para esto te recomendaría usar colas separadas por cliente y evitar el uso de variables globales (alguna vez leí que las variables globales son cosa del diablo xD)

Por ultimo, `remove()` espera el elemento a borrar, así que:

```
mensajes.remove(mensajes[mensaje])
```

debería ser:

```
mensajes.remove(mensaje)
```